# .INF files: how to concatenate values in [Strings] section?

Tags: inf

I have this in my .inf:

```
[Strings]
Driver_Name = "Our driver, build version 1112"
```

For some reason (better SVN hook compatibility - want to assing build number at each time I commit .sys), want this to be:

```
[Strings]
DrvVer = "1111";
Driver_Name = "Our driver, build version %DrvVer"
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't get processed, so `%DrvVer%` remains in place; the other idea is to use `"%Driver_Name% %DrvVer%"` construct outside of `[Strings]`, but don't sure how to join this parts, too.

Comment: why don't you merge text and versionnumber in your programmsource?

Comment: @endo.anaconda because its not the correct way to see version info for a constantly changing driver - for example, in driver install dialog, few older versions may be floating around - and I don't want to go to %windir%\inf and delete old files manually. Some other day, I would move the version information to some GUI statusbar and forget about it, but currently, want to have that info displayed at anywhere possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not familiar with SVN hooks but maybe some info about INF files will help you.

as far as i know %strings% are not interpreted within the String section.

If you want to concat them `"%Driver_Name% %DrvVer%"` is already the correct syntax,
but it doesnt work within the strings section

i wonder why you are putting the version in the strings section.
microsoft already implemented a special Version section for INF files.
please take a look at this links:

[INF Version Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[INF DriverVer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

you could lay out your INF like this:

```
[Strings]
DrvVer = 1111
BuildDate = 01/11/2011

[Version]
DriverVer=%BuildDate%,%DrvVer%
DriverPackageDisplayName="our driver, build version %DrvVer%"
```

it should work and looks more standard

Comment: thanks, here's some points :) and it seems that Microsoft doesn't care about this section in it's own DDK .inf examples.