# .INF files, any way to take pre-removal actions?

Tags: windows, driver, inf

It is wanted to catch a driver removal event within .INF (by having it to call custom dll/exe via some directive), neither by driver itself nor by userspace watchdog application.

Any hints on that?

*UPD*: seems that it can be *somehow* accomplished with either [co-installers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or by hacking around [notify objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *(which are also the answer for [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166260/inf-files-and-ncf-has-ui-how-to-write-dll-for-displaying-advanced-properties) about NDIS driver's property pages in network connection configuration)*

---

*(This is my third sequential question about that .INF files: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150520/inf-files-how-to-concatent-values-in-strings-section), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166260/inf-files-and-ncf-has-ui-how-to-write-dll-for-displaying-advanced-properties); guessing I just need to find a good place to discuss it - any recommendations (not MSDN please)?*)

Comment: You can do it with co-installers. Co-installers are just dlls which get called at several points of the installation of a driver. There is not much magic involved in writing one.

Comment: @Christopher, thanks for confirmation. Yes, it seems that http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/install/dif-codes_79pu.htm does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/install/dif-codes_79pu.htm

As Christopher confirmed my researches, would take into writing co-installer.